# problems installing adafruit-blinka on raspberrypi zero 2w

Tags: python, pip, raspberry-pi-zero, adafruit-circuitpython

**Background**

I am trying to install some needed dependencies on a raspberry pi zero2w and am running into an issue with the adafruit bno055 library, specifically its dependency adafruit-blinka. Due to the nature of the project the pi can only connect to local non-internet network. For this reason I have pre-downloaded all the libraries and dependencies through pip as `.tar.gz` files, as well all the `setuptools` and `wheel` `.whl` files. I then install them on the offline device.

**Issue**

I am running into the problem where I get `module board not found` after `import board` which is a required library in order to create an I2C connection in python

**What I have tried**

After looking at some other posts a common solution seems to be running the command

`sudo python3 pip install --force-reinstall adafruit-blinka`

for my case using source files I have tried both

`sudo python3 -m pip install --force-reinstall adafruit-blinka --no-index --find-links lib/`

`pip3 install --force-reinstall adafruit-blinka --no-index --find-links lib/`

as well as using the package name directly `Adafruit-Blinka-7.2.0.tar.gz`

these commands have mixed results, the majority of the time the command stalls for a long period of time on `Running command python setup.py egg_info` then errors with `python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1` and the one time it successfully reinstalled the package it still failed to `import board`